# How to set an app as default app in android programmatically

Tags: android, lockscreen

i'm working on a lock screen app for android , i want to make my app as the default lock screen app for mobile instead of the current lock screen ..  how is that done programmatically ?
any help ?

Comment: I highly doubt that this is possible. This would be a huge security risk.

Comment: but how is other lock screen apps working in the same way ?!

Comment: I guess you can't (luckily). Imagine if every app you install decides by itself to change the LockScreen you love with something you hate... possibly a virus.

Comment: I think this is not possible with non rooted phone. This can be down with rooted phones only as per my knowledge.

Comment: @DerGolem it will be an option that the user chooses ..

Comment: I hope it's not possible without the user explicit control. Anyway, I guess these apps change something into the OS configuration files, so, when restarted it will be the new default lockScreen.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace your lockscreen app with default lockscreen. What you can do is, you can make your app work as a lockscreen. User will have to disable all default locking mechanism (pin, gesture etc.). And your app will be triggered every time user switches on the screen. That's how other lockscreen apps (like Go Locker etc.) work.